# Allowing Geoserver users use REST just like web interface

Tags: rest, geoserver

I'm trying to make a web site on top of Geoserver. I allowed ROLE_AUTHORIZED in rest.properties file but now I'm facing an issue - when I use auth details of some user I create I can access any data on the Geoserver even though the user shouldn't have access to this and in the WEB interface they don't have access there.

For example I use GET request "/geoserver/rest/workspaces" with Basic Auth of user X (who is not admin) and I get list of 8 workspaces (cite, topp, sde, ...) even though when I log in when using WEB interface from user X I only see 1 workspace (topp).

Is there any way to only allow users do things in REST that they are allowed to do in WEB? Or is this approach not possible in Geoserver REST?
I searched everywhere but couldn't find any tutorial or question about this. Everyone uses admin to use REST from what I've seen.

Comment: Can they see inside the workspace?

Comment: Yes, I was able to get contents of workspaces, datastores and so on

Comment: What happens if you don't set ROLE-AUTHORIZED in rest.proptied?

Comment: Before that there was ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR, which only allowed admin users to send requests